# Did Winterbash cause more Suggested Edit reviews?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, statistics, winter-bash

Some hats this year were all about doing a lot of reviews (and keeping on doing more reviews until the other hat-hopefuls stopped ruining your streak). But did this cause any difference in the queues, in particular for Suggested Edits? When I've looked it's always been in the mid-to-high 400s, which means it's full or almost full. I was able to submit some suggested edits of my own but the whole process is extremely slow. (I've been waiting a week and a half on one edit.)

I'm curious to know if more rewards — even transient ones — had any impact. (Though these review hats are a bit too unclear and frustrating for my taste. Plus Steward badges are too hard to get to be a motivator, at least for me, even if I did just earn another.)

Was there an uptick in reviews? If there was, does that mean there was an uptick in suggested edits too, as there were more opportunities to submit them?

(I guess information on the other queues too would be nice, but that's not what I'm most interested in.)

Comment: A related question might be "at which point does adding more reviewers make the queue less full at all?" which may very well be "when Hell freezes over" aka "when there are no new users who use suggested edits to try to accrue rep".

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm a fairly active reviewer but have, in recent months, slipped back a bit on the Suggested Edits queue; it's one of the hardest workloads, IMHO, and I've been placing my efforts elsewhere – notably the (fast-growing) First Questions queue.

However, the prospect of a nice hat *did* inspire me to do a few days' worth of hard reviewing in Suggested Edits but I can't say I noticed many other "40 today" users listed on its [Stats Page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) (but that *may* just be a time-zone issue, as I'm currently on UTC+7, so I'd likely miss many US-based reviewers' daily stats).

BTW, I *did* (eventually) get the Harmony Hat:

[image: author's avatar with the Harmony Hat on]

---

As an aside: One thing that *may* improve the review rate for Suggested Edits would be (partial) anonymization of the reviews. There was a spell when I would skip those that I *should* have rejected because the proposer had enough reputation points to cast downvotes, and I went through a spell of receiving quite a few suspected "revenge" votes after unilateral rejections (i.e. "Reject and Edit").

By "partial anonymization" I mean much the same thing as is currently done for close votes. Those with the CV privilege can see who they are but low-rep users (including the OP) can't (easily) see the usernames.

Comment: I don't mind revenge downvotes; they're a badge of honor. What I *do* mind is 10 notifications about angry comments under my answers. Do you really think the anonymization will work? The timeline is just a click away.

Comment: Frankly, in all my time reviewing suggested edits (and I lean towards rejection 2:1), I have never got even a single revenge vote. Highly doubt anonymization will help except for making things more confusing (as it did for close votes) - what we need is a treatment of core problems (lackluster guidance, no robo reviewers, editor education, etc) rather than symptoms.